# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am casting one Image Button to a Link Button. But I'm getting the error: "Unable to Cast object of type Image Button to type LinkButton."

I am stuck, please guys help me out.

My Code :

```
LinkButton lnkbtnresult = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("Imgresult");
```

Comment: just to know why do you want to cast image button to link button, but not to ImageButton itself?

Comment: @KiranHegde its just for my personal Information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ImageButton` instead of `LinkButton` as you can not cast `ImageButton` to `LinkButton`

```
ImageButton imgbtnresult = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("Imgresult");
```

Once you have ImageButton, you can use its properties to assign to LinkButton object if really required.

```
LinkButton lnkButton = new LinkButton();
lnkButton.SomeProperty = imgbtnresult.SomeProperty;
```